# How to call a findOne function within another findOne function Node.js mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, jwt

Currently I am trying to write RESTapi for a website with users and flashcards. I am using a MERN stack in order to build this. The mongodb structure is the following:

```
//FlashCardSchema
const flashcardSchema = new Schema({
    deckID: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
    side1: { type: String, required: true },
    side2: { type: String, required: true }
}, { collection: "Flashcards" })

//FlashCardSetSchema
const flashcardDeckSchema = new Schema({
    collectionID: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
    setTitle: { type: String, required: true },
    flashcards: [flashcardSchema]
}, { collection: "Decks" });

//FlashCard DB Schemas
const flashcardCollectionSchema = new Schema({
    userID: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true
    },
    decks: [flashcardDeckSchema]
}, { collection: "FlashcardCollection" });
```

As you can see a flashcard collection is also connected to a user collection through its auto generated ID by mongodb. This means each user has only one "flashcardcollection" which is generated the same time a user registers.

Currently I am working on the login page and since this project is working with RESTApis I am using JWT tokens for login/authorization, and within these tokens I am passing on information such as UserID.

What I am trying to do currently is when someone tries to login, it verifies them, and finds the flashcardcollection assigned to them based on their userID. I ran into a problem of trying to call a findOne function within another findOne function and therefore I am not progressing.

Currently the login code looks as the following:

```
//Request email, password -> find user with email -> if no user throw error -> get password -> decrypt and compare -> if false throw error -> if true generate JWT token
//JWT secret == JWTSECRETKEY , Expires in 1 hour
exports.login = async (req, res, next) => {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    let loadedUser;
    let loadedFlashcardCollection;


    User.findOne({ email: email }).then(user => {
        if (!user) {
            const error = new Error('A user with this email does not exist');
            error.statusCode = 401;
            throw error;
        }
        loadedUser = user;
        return bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    })
        .then(isEqual => {
            if (!isEqual) {
                const error = new Error("Wrong Password");
                error.statusCode = 401;
                throw error;
            }
            loadedFlashcardCollection = getCollectionId(loadedUser._id);
            //Error caused by trying to insert flashcardID into  JWT token and not being able to get a respons
            const token = jwt.sign({ email: loadedUser.email, userId: loadedUser._id.toString(), loadedFlashcardCollection: loadedFlashcardCollection.toString() }, 'JWTSECRETTOKEN', { expiresIn: '2h' });
            res.status(200).json({ token: token, userId: loadedUser._id.toString(), collectionID: loadedFlashcardCollection.toString() })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            if (!err.statusCode) {
                err.statusCode = 500;
            }
            next(err);
        })
}



//function to find userID async way since it was needed.
async function getCollectionId(loadedUserID) {
    const collection = await flashcardCollection.findOne({ userID: loadedUserID });
    if (!collection) {
        error.statusCode = 401;
        throw new Error(`No collection found.`);
    }
    return collection._id;
}
```

and this returns the following when I try to log in through a POSTMAN

api:
{

"token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImV4YW1wbGUyQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsInVzZXJJZCI6IjY0NmRkZDZhMjJlMmZkYmJkYTFjYmU2OCIsImxvYWRlZEZsYXNoY2FyZENvbGxlY3Rpb24iOiJbb2JqZWN0IFByb21pc2VdIiwiaWF0IjoxNjg0OTUwNTk4LCJleHAiOjE2ODQ5NTc3OTh9.CRkMZ1m-CfZX7RLB-YXo6y9Ur_7tK4C1SPvCCQb-4ZE",

"userId": "646ddd6a22e2fdbbda1cbe68",

"collectionID": "[object Promise]"
}

can you guys help me figure out how to pass on the collectionID of the user in the same JWT token

I have tried creating async await functions but since i am new to NodeJs i am having a problem understanding how they work, therefore so far this was my closest attempt to success(at least its not throwing an error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since getCollectionId is asynchronous function and it return a promise from db, you need to wait for the response so it will be something like this,

.then( **async** (isEqual) => {

// your other code

loadedFlashcardCollection = **await** getCollectionId(loadedUser._id);

})

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , On a beginner level , you need to understand the **async/await** and **.then/catch**, [Async Await vs then/catch](https://medium.com/@dio.hamidou/async-await-vs-then-catch-4f64d42e6392) , [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) , this will give you bit insight .

We use **await** when we need to call and wait for **async** function or **Promise** .
In your case when, you call **getCollectionId**  without **await** ,inside your **getCollectionId**, your function will work but your **getCollectionId** will not wait for the function to completely finishes.
You are getting a promise object because **async** functions returns **Promise**, since without await, **getCollectionId** is not waiting to **settled** Promise ,so ,its in pending state,which is an initial state, neither fulfilled nor rejected.

---

So ,inside .then()

```
async(isEqual) => {
  if (!isEqual) {
    const error = new Error("Wrong Password");
    error.statusCode = 401;
    throw error;
  }
  loadedFlashcardCollection = await getCollectionId(loadedUser._id);
```

we used **async** in the callback function inside .then(), because **await** can only be used inside async function.